# Which method will call if i delete application from device in iphone

Tags: ios5, ios4, ios6.1

I am creating one iPhone server side application,in that when ever user will deletes the application i need to update the status of user.I am sending that request in application Terminate Method but it is not calling that method.Don't know where i need to send request inside application.If any one knows please help me as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

The application cannot know when it was terminated, that is something that the operating system knows about. And there is no way for your app to do anything when the app is deleted - it's deleted and can't do anything.

So, the simple answer is that it can't be done, because you can't get the operating system to tell you when it deletes an application.